# Redis command to get all available keys on Redis Cluster?

Tags: node.js, redis, redis-cluster

I am using this

```
redisManager.redisClient.keys('*example*', function (err, keys) {
})
```

But it only gives keys from only one of the redis cluster. How can I get keys from all cluster?

Comment: Shouldn't all nodes of a cluster share the same data and give the same result? Or are we talking multiple clusters here?

Comment: node-redis-cluster can do this. You can check it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-redis-cluster

Comment: @john Siu, all nodes giving separate data

Comment: can you show how you are setting the cluster value ?

Comment: Or you can use redisClient.zrange("example", 0, -1, function(err, replies) {

Comment: Which package are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get keys for all nodes using a single command. You have to get keys for all nodes and merge them.
Reference - https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1962

You can do something like.

```
var redis = require('redis');

redisConfig = new Array(
    {"port": 1234, "host": "192.168.1.2"},
    {"port": 5678, "host": "192.168.1.3"}
);

keys    = new Array();
allKeys = new Array();

for(i = 0; i < redisConfig.length; i++){
    redisClient = redis.createClient(redisConfig[i].port, redisConfig[i].host);    
      keys[i] = redisClient.keys('*example*', function (err, keys) {
      allkeys = [...new Set([...allKeys ,...keys[i]])];
    })
}
```

Comment: @Albin Mathew Does it help?

Comment: keys command is slower in redis and not recommend.

Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [`node-redisscan`](https://github.com/fritzy/node-redisscan) package? It allows you to use `SCAN` commands on Redis clusters.

You'd have to collect each matching key with the callback. Here's how you'd do it (directly lifted from the README file) -

```
var redisScan = require('redisscan');
var redis = require('redis').createClient();

redisScan({
    redis: redis,
    each_callback: function (type, key, subKey, value, done) {
        console.log(type, key, subKey, value);
        done();
    },
    done_callback: function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        redis.quit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code inorder to find keys from all cluster. Please refer to [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-redis-cluster) for more info.

```
    var RedisCluster = require('node-redis-cluster').RedisCluster;

    var rcluster = RedisCluster.create([
        { port: 6379, host: '10.0.0.1' },
        { port: 6379, host: '10.0.0.2' },
        { port: 6379, host: '10.0.0.3' },
    ]);
    rcluster.execAll('keys', ['*'], function(err, results) {
    /* results will be
    {
        '10.0.0.1:6379': [ // keys],
        '10.0.0.2:6379': [ // keys],
        '10.0.0.3:6379': [ // keys]
    }
    */
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys command not recommended to be used in productions mode.

From redis docs
Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.

Use scanStream Instead

```
            redisConnection = redisConnectionObject;

            const slaves = redisConnection.nodes("slave");

            config.info('number of slaves', slaves.length)


            let keys = [];
            let slavePromises = [];

            slaves.forEach((slave) => {
                let slaveCreate = new Promise((resolve) => {

                    const stream = slave.scanStream({
                        match: prefix
                    });

                    stream.on("data", (resultKeys) => {
                        keys = [...keys, ...resultKeys];
                    });
                    stream.on("end", () => {
                        resolve();
                    });
                });

                slavePromises.push(slaveCreate);
            });

            Promise.all(slavePromises).then(([slaveOneData, slaveTwoData]) => {

                keys = _.uniq(keys);

                resolveOne(keys);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted this from my C# code. You need to query across all servers and build your list of keys.

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');

async function getKeyList(servers, pattern) {
    const keyList = [];

    for (const server of servers) {
        if (!server.isConnected) continue;

        const keys = await server.keys(pattern);

        if (keys.length === 0) continue;

        keyList.push(...keys);
    }

    return keyList;
}

// Example usage:
const servers = [
    new Redis({ host: 'server1', port: 6379 }),
    new Redis({ host: 'server2', port: 6379 }),
    // Add more server configurations as needed
];

const pattern = 'your_pattern_here';

getKeyList(servers, pattern)
    .then((keyList) => {
        console.log('Keys:', keyList);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Run command `$ npm install redis` to install **redis**.

```
var redis = require('redis'),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(keys[i]);
  }
});
```

Comment: this is a solution for a standalone redis server, not for a redis cluster as the question states.